# padding/margin issue

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

[Live site.](http://growingedgecoaching.com)

I have a custom landing page for the Twenty Eleven Wordpress theme. I noticed that the search input in the navigation bar is slightly different on the landing page than the main site- on the landing, the search input seems smaller and the icon is off. What is the cause of this? I've tried using Firebug, but can't seem to locate the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If using Firebug side-by-side doesn't tell you, why do you think we can?

Comment: Hint: It appears to be the `#searchform`, not the `#s`.

Comment: No need to be harsh, and thanks for the hint.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be harsh, but it might have been *real*. Unless the `DOCTYPE` "fix" works, I imagine it has to do with something cascading stylistically. What that is, I would defer to Firebug to find.

Comment: I assumed it was something within the CSS, I just couldn't pinpoint exactly what it was.

Comment: There is no difference between any cascading styles from homepage to subpage, so you will not find anything within the CSS. Both pages link the same stylesheets and there is nothing inherited in one which is not inherited in the other. Without `<!DOCTYPE>` the browser doesn't know to which standard to render the HTML and CSS. Getting `<!DOCTYPE>` added to the homepage is the fix (not sure why you quoted it, Jared).

Comment: @SetSailMedia - Provide me a provable example and it'd be more than that. Note, I also upvoted your answer. `;)`

Comment: As soon as he updates his live site, we'll be able to see it working :} Here's further reading which explains better than I could: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html http://www.ericmeyeroncss.com/bonus/render-mode.html

Comment: @SetSailMedia - If you're not aware, `<base href="">` could be your friend.

Comment: @SetSailMedia - Note, the OP says that answers it (which I agree). Good work.

Comment: Quite the thread we built here :} at least it's resolved for OP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there is no `<!DOCTYPE>` specified on the homepage. The subpage includes these lines which the homepage does not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Of grave importance is the `<!doctype>` line, which on the subpage indicates HTML5 standard to the browser. :)

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->`

This bit is found at the top of header.php, which is presumably attached to every page, no?

Comment: It is attached only when `get_header()` is called. Compare your two templates and you'll find the homepage is likely missing that function. View source of your homepage, and you'll see it starts with `<head>`, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Padding means to space inside the border. And margin means to space outside the border.